# How can i change my localhost domain in Apache solr? (linux OS)

Tags: solr, solrcloud

i want to change domain..(linux)

For now the url to access solr is in the localhost domain:
http://localhost:8983/solr
I'd like to change it to another domain, but I don't know how to do it.
http://www.exmple.com:8983/solr

Comment: check if this of any help https://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-localhost-to-a-domain-name/

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti check it.!! but they're no help , I want to change my Linux os using the zookeeper help article but i don't  know how to do it, i need a basic step guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposing Solr directly on the internet usually isn't a good idea, but if you're *sure you've done the required security configuration*, you can configure the listening ip in `solr.in.sh`.

You can read about [this and multiple other recommendation in "Taking Solr to Production"](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/taking-solr-to-production.html#solr-hostname):

> Use the SOLR_HOST variable in the include file to set the hostname of the Solr server.
>
> `SOLR_HOST=solr1.example.com`

You might also have to configured `-Djetty.host=<ip to bind to>` when starting Solr (`SOLR_OPTS` in `solr.in.sh` or as an argument to `bin/solr`).

Otherwise I recommend placing a reverse proxy in front of Solr (for example nginx) configured with IP range limitations and a heavily restricted firewall, together with authentication configured in `security.json`.

Comment: can you write basic step by step how to start solr to production
just like: https://gist.github.com/kalharbi/fd29661b9926eb087c45  these

Comment: Sorry, but no; if you have specific questions, feel free to raise them as new questions or as a comment detailing what you're having trouble with. Add any new, relevant information to your question.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost helpful. @MatsLindh